# How to calculate a given font size in millimeters given a known DPI in C#?

Tags: c#

I need to print labels with a very specific font size, however the destination devices vary in DPI. Some have a 300 DPI resolution, others have 600 DPI, etc.

The following two lines give the same value, for some reason :

```
var f1 = new FormattedText(
    "M",
    CultureInfo.CurrentCulture,
    FlowDirection.LeftToRight,
    new Typeface(TypefaceName),
    12,
    DrawingColor,
    new NumberSubstitution(),
    1);

var f2 = new FormattedText(
    "M",
    CultureInfo.CurrentCulture,
    FlowDirection.LeftToRight,
    new Typeface(TypefaceName),
    12,
    DrawingColor,
    new NumberSubstitution(),
    100);

var h1 = f1.Height;  // = 14.583333333333334
var h2 = f2.Height;  // = 14.583333333333334
```

Both `h1` and `h2` gives the same `Height`, regardless of the `FormattedText`'s `pixelsPerDip` value. Likewise, is `14.583333333333334` the height in pixels?

What's the purpose of `pixelsPerDip` if whatever value I set restuls in the same `Height`?

I know that I can calculate some physical height using `DPI / 25.4 * y` (where `y` is a value in milimeters), but how do I calculate this value when creating a `FormattedText` instance? In other words, how to I create a `FormattedText` instance that will print some text with a very specific physical height?

Comment: As per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.formattedtext.height?view=net-5.0 FormattedText.Height AND the emSize constructor parameter are in 'device independent pixels' = 1/96th of an inch.  WPF is already abstracting away the DPI of the output device.

Comment: So, you are saying that the value of `pixelsPerDip` is device dependent, like CSS `zoom` property?

Comment: don't know about css zoom but, probably?.  I think there may be an XY issue here, since WPF is inherently DPI aware then you shouldn't NEED FormattedText to be able to achieve a fixed print size.  If everything is set up 'correctly' then WPF text with emSize 12 should print with M having a width of 12/96 inches.